# Computing the differential of the torus diffeomorphism $x\mapsto Ax \mod \mathbb Z^n$

Tags: differential-topology, smooth-manifolds, differential, tangent-spaces, diffeomorphism

Let $A \in M_n (\mathbb Z)$ such that $A^{-1} \in M_n(\mathbb Z)$. The torus $\mathbb T^n$ is $\mathbb R^n/\sim$ where $x \sim y \iff x-y\in \mathbb Z^n$. $A$ defines a diffeomorphism $f: \mathbb T^n \to \mathbb T^n$ by $f([x]_\sim) = [Ax]_\sim$. What is the differential $D_x f$ of $f$?

Using the definition of the tangent space as equivalence classes of curves I tried calculating $D_x f ([\gamma_i])$ where $\gamma_i (t) = x + te_i$ form a basis for $T_x \mathbb T^n$, but couldn't get to something meaningful.

Comment: For $v\in T_p\Bbb T^2 \simeq \Bbb R^2$ (which is a canonical isomorphism), $ \gamma(t)=p+tv$, then $f(\gamma(t))=f(p+tv) =Ap + tAv$, and this, $\gamma'(0) =Av$, so that $D_pf(v) = Av$, with $A\colon \Bbb R^2 \to \Bbb R^2$.

Comment: (obviously, replace all $2$ by $n$ in by previous comment)